# Is MySQL smart enough to stop considering rows once HAVING condition must be true?

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

Imagine a query like

```
SELECT col1
FROM t
GROUP BY col2
HAVING COUNT(col3) > 1;
```

where there's a usable index on col2. As MySQL scans the col2 index and calculates COUNT(col3), will it stop counting as soon the count exceeds 1 and scan ahead to the next unique col2 value? Or will it consider every row and get an accurate count, then compare it against 1 once it's done aggregating in full?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is informed speculation.  MySQL is not smart enough to stop when the `HAVING` clause is true.  Why?  Because MySQL does the `GROUP BY` first and then does the `ORDER BY`.  As far as I know, it does not push the filtering into the aggregation step -- even when using an index.

Let met ignore the `SELECT col1`, which makes no sense in this query.

If `col2`/`col3` pairs are unique, then you might get better performance with:

```
SELECT col1
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t t2
              WHERE t2.col2 = t.col2 AND t2.col3 <> t.col3
             );
```

This will stop at the first `col3` row that matches.  If the situation is that you are really checking for `NULL` values of `col3`, then:

```
SELECT col1
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t t2
              WHERE t2.col2 = t.col2 AND t2.col3 IS NOT NULL AND t2.id <> t.id
             ) AND
      col3 IS NOT NULL;
```

These latter two queries assume you have an index on `t(col2, col3)`.